# How to shift particular row to right in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a scenario where I am trying to load a CSV into R. I cannot modify the CSV, because it is a system file

Here are few rows of the CSV, which I am working on. I want to shift the row no. 1 to its right, becuase the column headers are not correct in CSV and I have to remove NULL columns after that.

Here are some of the my `data.frame` rows

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9
1   NA  Cy1 NA  Cy2 NA  Cy3 NA  Cy4 NA
2   A1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   A2  NA  94  NA  25  NA  11  NA  119
4   A3  NA  94  NA  25  NA  13  NA  198
5   B1  NA  94  NA  32  NA  113 NA  129
6   B2  NA  100 NA  95  NA  102 NA  12
7   B3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
8   B4  NA  120 NA  14  NA  110 NA  25
9   C2  NA  119 NA  11  NA  40  NA  25
10  C3  NA  198 NA  13  NA  45  NA  32
```

Here I am trying to acheive something like,

```
    V1  V3  V5  V7  V9
1   NA  Cy1 Cy2 Cy3 Cy4
2   A1  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   A2  94  25  11  119
4   A3  94  25  13  198
5   B1  94  32  113 129
6   B2  100 95  102 12
7   B3  NA  NA  NA  NA
8   B4  120 14  110 25
9   C2  119 11  40  25
10  C3  198 13  45  32
```

As you see, I have to shift the first row of `data.frame` to its `right` and later delete 'NA' columns.

Can someone help me on the same. Thanks in advance

Thanks,
KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
V1 <- c(NA, "A1", "A2")
V2 <- c("Cy1", NA, NA)
V3 <- c(NA, NA, 94)
V4 <- c("Cy2", NA, NA)
V5 <- c(NA, NA, 25)
V6 <- c("Cy3", NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6)
df

cols <- c(5,3)

df
for (j in cols) {
df[1,j] <- paste(df[1,j-1])
}
df

for (j in cols) {
df[ ,j-1] <- NULL
}
df
```

The above code is a minimum working example. Let it run and see if it does what you want (it should).
You will need to specify the columns which you want to keep (read: all columns which you want the values shifted **to**) with their number in the object `cols` in **descending** order (or deleting the columns will get messed up).

(I am a Stata person, so to the R-pros out there: please excuse my lack of using `apply` instead of loops.)

Comment: Hi. I used `read.csv` function only. And `A1, A2, ...` are not row names, those are the cell values. Also, `Cy1, Cy2, ...` are also not column names. I want to shift any particular row. I choose that row.

Comment: @user3444971 I updated the answer, check for usefulness

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting the below error, while doing the same.

`> dim(y.new)
[1] 42  9
> 
> cols <- c(8,42)
> 
> for (j in cols){
+   y.new[1,j] <- paste(y.new[1,j-1])
+ }
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, j, value = character(0)) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "NA") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> `

Comment: sorry my editing bad. I tried to format the comment well, but could not do so.

Comment: As I said, you need to specify the columns which you want to keep with their number in the object `cols` in descending order.
`cols <- c(8, 42)` does not confirm to that statement.
Sidenote: if you want to change the row that the operation is applied on, you will need to change the first argument in the square brackets of `df[1,j] <- paste(df[1,j-1])`. However, if you have to do this for multiple rows you will have to wrap another loop around it to replace everything first, and then after all replacements delete the NA columns.

Comment: Regarding my bad wording on "you need to specify the columns which you want to keep with their number in the object `cols` in descending order": It means you need to write e.g.: `cols <- c(7,5,3)` if you want the contents of columns 6, 4 and 2 (in row 1) shifted to the right and subsequently have columns 6, 4 and 2 deleted.

Comment: Yes. That was my problem. That worked very well for me. I specified `cols <- c(11,9,7,5)`. I got some warning like `invalid factor level, NA generated`. I started reading CSV with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and that solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your time.